# How to get json data in android as hasmap?

Tags: android

how to get the JSON as has map and stored it in a array list and then getting them as string and storing in list and getting one by one from the list?

Comment: You can store the data directly in an arraylist and then display them one by one in a list or however you want to display using the index value. The parsing depends on the JSON format in which you are getting the data.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same work before. Check my activity:

```
public class BandMembers extends ListActivity {
    public static final String TAG_MEMBER_NAME = "member_name";
    public static final String TAG_MEMBER_SKILL = "member_skill";
    public static final String TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE = "member_thumb_image";
    public static String URL = "http://clients.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/web_service/mainAPI.php"; 

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> memberList;
    String responseData = null;
    private ListView listView;
    TextView title;
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options;


    public static class Config {
        public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.band_members);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "font.TTF");
        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBandMembers);
        title.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        title.setTypeface(tf);
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.loading)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image_available)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image_available)
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();

        memberList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        new AsyncData().execute();
    }

    class AsyncData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BandMembers.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rquest","{\"method\":\"band_members\",\"body\":[{}]}"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                responseData = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                try {
                    JSONArray data = new JSONArray(responseData);
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        String memberName = c.getString(TAG_MEMBER_NAME);
                        String memberSkill = c.getString(TAG_MEMBER_SKILL);
                        String memberImage = c.getString(TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE);
                        map.put(TAG_MEMBER_NAME, memberName);
                        map.put(TAG_MEMBER_SKILL, memberSkill);
                        map.put(TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE, memberImage);
                        memberList.add(map);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(new BandMemberAdapter(memberList));
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    public class BandMemberAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> memberListTemp;
        HashMap<String, String> myData;

        public BandMemberAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> memberList1) 
        {
            memberListTemp=memberList1;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return memberListTemp.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            TextView textName;
            TextView textSkill;
            ImageView image;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.band_member_row_file, parent, false);
                image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageMember);
                textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMemberName);
                textSkill = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMemberInfo);
            } else {
                return convertView;
            }

            myData = memberListTemp.get(position);
            Typeface tfb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fontbold.TTF");
            textName.setText(myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_MEMBER_NAME));
            textName.setTypeface(tfb);
            textSkill.setText(myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_MEMBER_SKILL));
            textSkill.setTypeface(tfb);
            String uri =  "http://clients.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx/web_admin/assets/images/bandmembers/thumbs/" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE).replace(" ", "%20");

            imageLoader.displayImage(uri, image, options);

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is what i know but i need to know about how to show this as a list in viewpager.